# Understanding a step in a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

The question and its solution are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My question is:**

In the last line, why we are sure that $(Av)^H (Av) \geq 0.$? could anyone explain this for me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(Av)^*(Av)$ is another way to write $\langle Av,Av \rangle$, the inner product in $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Could you prove this please as I can not see it?

Comment: If we have two vectors, $$x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} \textrm{ and } y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} \textrm{ in } \mathbb C^n$$ then we see that $$\begin{align} \langle x,y \rangle &= x_1\overline{y_1} + x_2\overline{y_2} + \cdots + x_n\overline{y_n} \\ &= \big( \begin{matrix} \overline{y_1} & \overline{y_2} & \cdots & \overline{y_n} \end{matrix} \big) \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} \\ &= y^*x \end{align}$$

Comment: there is something wrong in the latex

Comment: perfectly done thank you :))

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: and why $\lambda$ strictly > 0?

Comment: It could be $0$. If $A$ is a singular matrix, then there is a nonzero vector, $v$, in the nullspace of $A$, so, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^*A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: but the question want us to show that $\lambda$ is strictly positive.

Comment: The question says *positive* only, possible it may be more appropriate to say *non-negative*. Just consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and then the matrix $$A^*A = \begin{pmatrix} 2&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 2$ and $\lambda_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $u=(u_{1},...,u_{n}),v=(v_{1},...,v_{n})\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$, we define 
\begin{align*}
\left<u,v\right>=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}\overline{v_{i}}.
\end{align*}
It is routine to check this is an inner product.

On the other hand, if we treat the elements in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ as column vector, that is, $n\times 1$ matrix, then the conjugate transpose $u^{\ast}$ is such that $u^{\ast}u=\left<\overline{u},u\right>=\|u\|^{2}$, where $\overline{u}=\left(\overline{u_{1}},...,\overline{u_{n}}\right)$.

Comment: why you have bar over the $u$ in your last line?

Comment: Conjugate transpose means that you switch column to row, and also give each of the elements their conjugate, the bar.

Comment: And how this gives me the first equality ?

Comment: Of course then $(Av)^{H}Av=\|Av\|^{2}\geq 0$.

Comment: the first equality in your last line?

Comment: So it is a product of $[\overline{u_{1}},...,\overline{u_{n}}]$ with the column vector $[u_{1},...,u_{n}]$ (I cannot type this as column form, but it is vertical column, can you imagine it?), you can simply expand, you will see the result immediately.

Comment: but shouldnot the column vector be transpose also?

Comment: All I want to say is that, $u^{H}v$ is the product of a row vector with a column vector, row comes first, so it the product of $1\times n$ with $n\times 1$ matrices, the result is $1\times 1$ matrix, which is a number.

Comment: And where is the conjugate sign?

Comment: The row vector carries all its elements with conjugate signs.

Comment: And why the conjugate sign is not on the second component as you defined the inner product?

Comment: is this because the 2 components of the inner product contains the same vector?

Comment: The summands are $\overline{u_{i}}\overline{\overline{u_{i}}}=\overline{u_{i}}u_{i}=|u_{i}|^{2}$.