# Proving that every eigenvalue is $Positive$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

In completion of this question :

[Understanding a step in a solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466442/understanding-a-step-in-a-solution/3466444?noredirect=1#comment7126536_3466444)

The link contains the proof that $\lambda $ is nonnegative, but the question requires it to be positive, can anyone help me to prove this?

Comment: So you mean that the question is wrong? @KaboMurphy

Comment: It is not uncommon for people to say positive for non-negative and increasing for non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the zero matrix then $0$ is an eigen value of $A^{H}A$. You cannot prove that the eigen value is $>0$.

Comment: So you mean that the question is wrong?